# youtube-dl sometime hangs with "[ffmpeg] Correcting container"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, containers, youtube-dl

Ubuntu 16.04

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --version
2018.05.09
```

I have a bash script that attemts to download a youtube video. The output is below. The problem is that sometimes it works perfectly (completes quickly).
But most of the time it hangs on "Correcting container....". Does anyone know why?

```
+ /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl --verbose -x 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HVWitAW-Qg'

[debug] System config: []

[debug] User config: []

[debug] Custom config: []

[debug] Command-line args: [u'--verbose', u'-x', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HVWitAW-Qg']

[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs UTF-8, out UTF-8, pref UTF-8

[debug] youtube-dl version 2018.05.09

[debug] Python version 2.7.12 (CPython) - Linux-4.4.0-124-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial

[debug] exe versions: avconv 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, avprobe 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, ffmpeg 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, ffprobe 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, rtmpdump 2.4

[debug] Proxy map: {}

[youtube] 8HVWitAW-Qg: Downloading webpage

[youtube] 8HVWitAW-Qg: Downloading video info webpage

[youtube] 8HVWitAW-Qg: Extracting video information

[debug] Invoking downloader on u'https://r5---sn-5uaeznkl.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1526159728&source=youtube&key=yt6&mime=audio%2Fmp4&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cusequic%2Cexpire&keepalive=yes&lmt=1518142590597815&dur=231.131&mv=m&mt=1526137933&ms=au%2Conr&signature=18BB34F3716B412AC5757872DD2AF402B6EE20D2.43D2E68B5A5ED2E2D3076DF9264B9BB723484821&ip=71.81.217.251&c=WEB&initcwndbps=1583750&mn=sn-5uaeznkl%2Csn-p5qs7n7l&clen=3671757&gir=yes&id=o-AOxj8Rg2IuZek8KwvgPy-N7_FSGzxQ0Zl2HX1T4gepLf&ipbits=0&fvip=5&ei=EAX3WqbOH8fg4QSlkrGoAg&pl=20&mm=31%2C26&itag=140&usequic=no&requiressl=yes&ratebypass=yes'

[download] Destination: Top 10 cute kitten videos compilation-8HVWitAW-Qg.m4a

[download] 100% of 3.50MiB in 00:00

[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "Top 10 cute kitten videos compilation-8HVWitAW-Qg.m4a"

[debug] ffmpeg command line: avconv -y -i 'file:Top 10 cute kitten videos compilation-8HVWitAW-Qg.m4a' -c copy -f mp4 'file:Top 10 cute kitten videos compilation-8HVWitAW-Qg.temp.m4a'

^C
ERROR: Interrupted by user
```

Comment: That's fake ffmpeg - get real ffmpeg from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html. Add following args to your yt-dl command: `--prefer-ffmpeg --ffmpeg-location PATH` where PATH is the folder with ffmpeg.

Comment: This problem is almost certainly in avconv and unrelated to youtube-dl (full disclosure: as the long-time lead developer of youtube-dl I may be biased). When it "hangs", how long does it take? What's the CPU and RAM usage when this happens? If you attach `strace` to the avconv process when it hangs, what do you see? You can pass in `--fixup warn` to youtube-dl to prevent that avconv call, but there will be another one necessary for the audio conversion anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the latest ffmpeg and use the following:

/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -q --no-warnings --fixup --prefer-ffmpeg -- 
   ffmpeg-location /usr/local/bin -x "$1"

I get audio files consistently now (ogg, opus, m4a, etc). But errors still print on the screen. Good enough for now.